# How to read multiple contents in HttpResponseMessage()?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, httpresponsemessage

I'm creating an `HttpResponseMessage` object and sending it back to the caller. I also pass in a `Dictionary<string,object>`.

```
return HttpContext.Current.Request.CreateResponse(httpStatusCode.Ok, mydict);
```

How does the caller access the dictionary on their end? They get back the `HttpResponseMessage` type but trying to read the `Content` object on it hasn't produce anything like a dictionary.

Comment: What has it produces? Can you show the result? If the content-type is JSON, then it will not look like a dictionary. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net)

Comment: Is the caller another .net app? Or an ajax call? Serializing a dictionary won't really result in the type of object you might expect.

Comment: No JSON but I see now the dictionary is flattened into a string when I use Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result. I believe I just need to serialize the string back into a dictionary?

The caller is a .net client app.

Comment: Yeah the normal way is to deserialize the string back into a dictionary but since you are using an "object" as the dictionary value you may run into some issues because the deserializer will not know what kind of object it is deserializing.

However, if you are only using string values (or any other type not ambiguous) then you will be ok.